# How to change the format of the list element?

Tags: python, python-2.7

For example, I have a list

```
a = ["ID:123","ID:321"]
print a
```

I prefer output like:

```
[123,321]
```

without 'ID:'. I've been looking for solutions but they all `remove()` element， not part of them. So need some help here!

Comment: That's not valid syntax.

Comment: It it possible you have a list of dictionaries, like `a = [{ID:123}, {ID:321}]`?

Comment: sorry guys forget `""`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a = ["ID:123","ID:321"]          # I suppose you mean this

print [elem[3:] for elem in a]   # This is a solution
```

Comment: this is cool mate. Thanks

Comment: Or maybe `int(elem[3:])`